# Report Builder 2016 Problem

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, reporting-services

I'm using Reporting Service with SharePoint Mode (Not native mode). I've a document library with folders, subfolders and files. But the Report Builder can not retrieve files and subfolder, it gets only root folders. There is no solution like Scope="RecursiveAll" in the Query. The possible solution is installing Reporting Services with native mode and query the list with web service. Do you have any suggest for this situation?

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround to show all files in document library in SSRS report, you can

> Modify the Library view to `Show all items without folders`

**Steps:**

- Open Document Library.
- From the above ribbon, click on `modify view`,
- Below `Folders`,  Specify to view all items at once.

[image]

- Hence, you can show all files in the document library whatever it's inside folder or subfolder in your SSRS report easily!

[image]

**By the way,** As shown above (in the second column), there is a hidden field called the `[Server_Relative_URL]` that show the report path, so you can show it in your report to know where is your file specifically stored?

Also, you can try to extract the root path from this field for each item, and then try to group by it as shown in the first column as mentioned at https://blog.devoworx.net/2018/02/04/show-sharepoint-document-library-files-in-ssrs-recursively/